# ajax validation in partial rendering i yii

Tags: php, yii

I created a form in my popup using partial rendering method

```
$userComment=new Comments; 

                $PopupdetailText .= $this->renderPartial('/comments/_form', array('model' => $userComment),TRUE);
```

But now I face the problem that the form is not validating.But it works when I  render the form
**_form**

```
    <?php
/* @var $this CommentsController */
/* @var $model Comments */
/* @var $form CActiveForm */
?>

<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'comments-form',
    'action' => Yii::app()->createUrl('comments/create'), 
        'enableAjaxValidation' => FALSE,
        'enableClientValidation' => true,
        'clientOptions' => array('validateOnSubmit' => true,),
        'htmlOptions' => array(
            'class' => 'form',
        )
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'type'); ?>
        <?php  
         echo $form->dropDownList($model,'type',
         array(""=>"Select Type","0"=>"Offer","1"=>"Events"),
         array('style' => 'width:220px;','class'=>'form-control','disabled'=>false,)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'type'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'offereventid'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'offereventid',array('style' => 'width:500px;','class'=>'form-control','disabled'=>false,)); ?>

        <?php echo $form->error($model,'offereventid'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'name',array('style' => 'width:500px;','class'=>'form-control','disabled'=>false,)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'email'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'email',array('style' => 'width:500px;','class'=>'form-control','disabled'=>false,)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'email'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'comment'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'comment',array('style' => 'width:500px;','class'=>'form-control','disabled'=>false,)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'comment'); ?>
    </div>


    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save',array('class'=>'btn btn-success','style'=>'color:black')); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

Can any one tell me what I am missing?How can I achieve the validaton

Comment: Can you set 'enableAjaxValidation' => True and check once again, also check request using network tab of console

Comment: @GaneshGhalame I already tried that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my question.

```
$userComment = new Comments; 

                    $PopupdetailText .= $this->renderPartial('//comments/_form', array('model' => $userComment,'id'=>$id),TRUE,TRUE);
                    $PopupdetailText.='</div>
```

You need to add an True

Thank you for all your supports

Answer (score 0):

There is render method as [renderAjax](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-controller.html#renderAjax%28%29-detail). This will also populate the default yii2 active form validation code.